# ScrollsToTop is not working when UIVeiwController is presented from ios8 extension

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios8-extension

ScrollsToTop is not working when UIVeiwController is presented from ios8 extension. 
But it is working if we presented it from inside the app. Can anyone help? sample code is shared here.

```
UIScrollView * scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) ];
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
scrollview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
scrollview.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slide1"]];
[scrollview addSubview:imageView];
scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator =YES;
scrollview.scrollsToTop = YES;
scrollview.delegate = self;
UIViewController *a = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
a.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[a.view addSubview:scrollview];
[self presentViewController:a animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues & resolved using code bellow.

Some change has done in `xcode6`. Try this code to make `scrollview` to top.

```
 [self.ScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:YES];
```